# Control Output Shock From Cockroft-Walton Doubler

Tags: voltage, control, 555, multiplier

so I'm building a device that charges a capacitor bank to between 1kV and 2kV. The goal here is to use a 555 timer to control a shock pulse from the capacitor bank. I can touch the ouputs of the bank, and I get an initial shock, but if I hold my finger on the outputs, the shock is much less because the capacitors can't charge up if something is shorting the outputs. I'd like to be able to allow the bank to charge up, and then selectively discharge the bank with a timer. I'm basically looking for the functionality you'd get from a spark gap, but I want to be able to control the shock pulse with a timer. I was thinking of using a timer to switch a transistor or mosfet, but the voltage is too high and I'm having a difficult time finding one with a high enough breakdown voltage.

Is there any other way I can selectively control the output shock?

Comment: There is a limit to N stages of doubling initial pulse due to sum of series resistance which becomes quite high going from 15V to 2kV.  This is a suboptimal approach. (NG)

Comment: Could a thyristor or IGBT module work? There are some quite high-voltage ones available. In fact, digi-key even has some single thyristors rated for up to 6kV, though they're quite expensive and you have to buy at least thirty of them. I also wonder if you could do something with vacuum triodes... Might be a cheaper option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also controllable spark-gaps.

They're from the way-back-when LEDs weren't powerful enough to illuminate an entire room for 1/125th of a second.

Some people call them Flash tubes. It'll be a big one for kV ranges, but hey, old crap should be cheap on eBay.

---

All fun aside, next to using second hand flash tubes, you can also get 3-terminal enclosed spark gaps which offer similar functionality without wasting energy on making a visible light flash. Often to be found in the "Gas Discharge Tube Isle". They have a small gap and a large gap, you use a 1:100 insulated ignition coil or any other scheme to create a small high voltage pulse on the middle pin, referenced to the pin with the shortest gap distance. This polarises the gas(ses) inside, which lowers the internal resistance and allows the main gap to spark.

Comment: Isn't what you described just a thyratron?

Comment: @Felthry A thyratron is more controllable and much less cheaply available.

Comment: Ahh ok. This sounds perfect for my application. Also, @WhatRoughBeasthas a great option, as well. I'll look up these components and see what I can find. Thank you both for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The length of the discharge time can be controlled by the selection of the capacitor bank value.

Answer (score 0):

There is, as I understand the question, a fairly simple solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsER7O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course there is a slight problem - what sort of relay will hold off kilovolts?

Ah. Well, it's called a vacuum relay. For an array of surplus vacuum relays, see [here](http://www.surplussales.com/relays/REVacRel-1.html). Depending on how much you're willing to spend, you can easily handle 10 kV and 50 amps of discharge current.

They are physically big and way expensive, but you didn't say that would be a problem.